# Java 2D Animation, why doesn't currentFrame get updated every time the game ticks?

Tags: java, swing, animation, 2d-games

I have been working on this game for quite a bit now. I looked through some of the game loops and animation systems online. After I felt confident about coding my own animation system, I came up with this one. I think it should work like a charm but currentFrame variable seems to stuck at '1' so my animation doesn't play. Can get some help for this? What did I code wrong?

Here are the four classes (GamePanel, Player, Animation, Frames) that are used for the system:

GamePanel class:

```
package main;

import entity.*;
import animation.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public static final String GAME_VERSION = "0.0.1a";
    public static final String GAME_TITLE = "Test " + GAME_VERSION +;

    public static final int ORIGINAL_TILE_SIZE = 32;
    public static final int SCALE = 2;
    public static final int SCALED_TILE_SIZE = ORIGINAL_TILE_SIZE * SCALE;
    public static final int[] SCREEN_RATIO = {16, 9};
    public static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = SCREEN_RATIO[0] * SCALED_TILE_SIZE;
    public static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = SCREEN_RATIO[1] * SCALED_TILE_SIZE;
    public static final int MAX_TPS = 60;

    public int fpsCount;
    public int tpsCount;

    private JFrame frame;
    public boolean isRunning = false;

    KeyHandler keyHandler = new KeyHandler();
    Thread gameThread;
    Player player = new Player(this, keyHandler);

    public GamePanel(){
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.addKeyListener(keyHandler);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.setFocusable(true);

        frame = new JFrame(GAME_TITLE);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public synchronized void start(){
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
        isRunning = true;
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long deltaTime = 0;
        long tickInterval = 1000000000 / MAX_TPS;

        while(isRunning == true){

            long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            deltaTime += (currentTime - lastTime) / tickInterval;

            if(deltaTime >= 1){

                Update();

                lastTime = currentTime;
                deltaTime -= 1;

                if(tpsCount == 60){

                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");

                    System.out.println("FPS: " + fpsCount + " TPS: " + tpsCount);
                    System.out.println("W: " + player.isPressedW);
                    System.out.println("S: " + player.isPressedS);
                    System.out.println("A: " + player.isPressedA);
                    System.out.println("D: " + player.isPressedD);
                    System.out.println("Direction: " + player.direction);
                    System.out.println("Idle: " + player.isIdle);
                    System.out.println("Animating: " + player.testAnimation.isRunning);
                    System.out.println("Current Animation Frame: " + player.testAnimation.currentFrame);

                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");

                    tpsCount -= 60;
                    fpsCount = 0;

                }
            }

            Render();

        }

    }

    public void Update() {

        player.update();

        tpsCount++;

    }

    public void Render(){

        repaint();

        fpsCount++;

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { //This is called 'repaint' in the Render method

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        player.render(g2d);
        g2d.dispose();

    }

}
```

Player class:

```
package entity;

import main.*;
import animation.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Player extends Entity {

    GamePanel gp;
    KeyHandler kh;
    public String direction;
    public boolean isIdle;

    Frames idleSouth, idleNorth, idleEast, idleWest;
    Frames movingSouth, movingNorth, movingEast, movingWest;

    Animation movementAnimation;

    public Frames testFrames = new Frames("player/move_animations", 1, 8);
    public Animation testAnimation = new Animation(testFrames, true);


    public boolean isPressedS, isPressedW, isPressedD, isPressedA;


    public Player(GamePanel gp, KeyHandler kh){

        this.gp = gp;
        this.kh = kh;
        setDefaultProperties();

    }

    public void setDefaultProperties(){

        x = 320;
        y = 320;
        speed = 240 / this.gp.MAX_TPS;
        maxHealth = 100;
        curHealth = 100;
        direction = "South";


    }

    public void update(){

        testAnimation.update();

        isPressedS = kh.pressed_S;
        isPressedW = kh.pressed_W;
        isPressedD = kh.pressed_D;
        isPressedA = kh.pressed_A;

        if(kh.pressed_S != true && kh.pressed_W != true && kh.pressed_D != true && kh.pressed_A != true){
            isIdle = true;
            testAnimation.start();
        }else{
            isIdle = false;
            testAnimation.stop();
        }

        if(kh.pressed_S == true){
            direction = "South";
            moveSouth();
        }
        if(kh.pressed_W == true){
            direction = "North";
            moveNorth();
        }
        if(kh.pressed_D == true){
            direction = "East";
            moveEast();
        }
        if(kh.pressed_A == true){
            direction = "West";
            moveWest();
        }

    }

    public void render(Graphics2D g2d){

        g2d.drawImage(testAnimation.getFrame(), x, y, GamePanel.SCALED_TILE_SIZE, GamePanel.SCALED_TILE_SIZE, null);

    }

    public void moveSouth(){
        y += speed;
    }
    public void moveNorth(){
        y -= speed;
    }
    public void moveEast(){
        x += speed;
    }
    public void moveWest(){
        x -= speed;
    }



}
```

Animation class:

```
package animation;

import main.*;
import entity.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Animation {

    public boolean isRunning = false;
    public boolean isContinuous;

    private int frameTimer;
    public int currentFrame = 1;

    Frames frames;

    public Animation(Frames frames, boolean isCountinuous){

        this.frames = frames;
        this.isContinuous = isCountinuous;

    }

    public void update(){

        if(this.isRunning == true){

            if(this.isContinuous == true){

                if(frameTimer == 14){
                    if(currentFrame < frames.frameCount){
                        currentFrame++;
                        frameTimer -= 14;
                    }else if(currentFrame == frames.frameCount){
                        currentFrame = 1;
                        frameTimer -= 14;
                    }

                }else{
                    frameTimer++;
                }

            }else if(this.isContinuous == false){

                if(frameTimer == 14){
                    if(currentFrame < frames.frameCount){
                        currentFrame++;
                        frameTimer -= 14;
                    }else if(currentFrame == frames.frameCount){
                        currentFrame = 1;
                        frameTimer -= 14;
                        this.stop();
                    }

                }else{
                    frameTimer++;
                }

            }

        }

    }

    public void start(){

        frameTimer = 0;
        isRunning = true;

    }

    public void stop(){

        frameTimer = 0;
        currentFrame = 1;
        isRunning = false;

    }

    public BufferedImage getFrame(){

        return frames.framelist.get(currentFrame - 1);

        // return null;

    }

}
```

Frames class:

```
package animation;

import main.*;
import entity.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Frames {

    public BufferedImage spriteSheet;
    public int frameCount;
    public ArrayList<BufferedImage> framelist;

    public Frames(String path, int row, int frameCount){

        this.frameCount = frameCount;

        try {
            spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + path + ".png"));
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        framelist = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int col = 1; col <= frameCount; col++){

            framelist.add(spriteSheet.getSubimage((GamePanel.ORIGINAL_TILE_SIZE * col) - GamePanel.ORIGINAL_TILE_SIZE, (GamePanel.ORIGINAL_TILE_SIZE * row) - GamePanel.ORIGINAL_TILE_SIZE, GamePanel.ORIGINAL_TILE_SIZE, GamePanel.ORIGINAL_TILE_SIZE));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a Swing Timer to drive the game loop to avoid Swing threading issues like this code is going to run into. Also, Google "concurrency in Swing", a tutorial that will help you better understand Swing threading issues. Also, never dispose of a Graphics object given to you by the JVM (such as in your paintComponent method). Only dispose of one that you yourself create de novo.